# Can an iPhone OS app do a search of the device's filesystem?

Tags: iphone, sandbox

Can I do a search of the iPhone filesystem from within an application? I need to search an iPhone OS device and return a list of all apps installed on an iPhone OS device. I am fairly aware of Apple's restrictions and rules concerning what apps can and mostly cannot do outside of the sandbox -- and know that aside from the *Photo Album* an *Address Book* (via specified classes) an application is not allowed to access much of anything outside of its home directory (sandbox) for security. But the boundaries are fuzzy.

Anyway, back to the question: Can UISearchBarDelegate (or any other class/protocol) allow me to search the iPhone device?

Comment: Did you find a solution/workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunatly you are still sandboxed, the only way to access the devices' filesystem is to create an application that is a jailbreak designed application.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly true - the app *FileSystem*, for example, allows you to browse the iOS file structure and view many (though not all) of the files.  You can access almost all of the files from the iTunes backup however.